# Clojure : Defining a forv macro using for

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm trying to write my second macro but I'm completely stuck here.

I would like to avoid writing everytime `(vec (for [...]))` so I'm trying to write a `forv` macro like filterv, mapv, etc.
I work mostly with vectors in my programs since I need to have access to the index because I use external buffers/descriptors to fasten matrix process. 
I have written many ***v like functions (also adaptative functions like `fmap` )but I'm sticked with for.

So I wrote

```
(defmacro forv
  [seq-exprs body-expr]
  (vec (for (vec seq-exprs) body-expr)))
```

I tried with seq-exprs alone, it does not work. To be honest I tried also ~ and so on but I do not know how it works, I succeed in my first macro because it was far easier.

Clojure tell me that for requires a vector for binding.

Can someone help me and also explain what I am missing ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why would you need to explicitly convert `for` return values to vectors?

Comment: I added teh explnation. The general is that I frequently need to have have acces to the index or by index for an algo.

Comment: [@nha's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39352894/1562315) passes some pathological calls that [@AlanThompson's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39353236/1562315) detects. For example, given `(forv '() 888)`, the former returns `[]`, whereas the latter detects an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the one built [into the Tupelo Library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  Source code is here:  https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/core.cljc#L181

```
(defmacro forv
  "Like clojure.core/for but returns results in a vector.  Equivalent to (into [] (for ...)). Not
   lazy."
  [& body]
  `(vec (for ~@body)))
```

Comment: Thanks too, Seems not that different for the other so I chose the first one posted !

Comment: Yes, but mine was simpler.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
;;
;; you want something like that in the end: (forv [x (range 2)] x)  => (vec (for [x (range 2)] x))
;;

(defmacro forv
  [seq-exprs body-expr]
  `(vec (for [~@seq-exprs] ~body-expr)))
;;
;; check quote and unquote
;; in particular, check the tricky bit is https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/unquote-splicing
;;
```

Edit: I based my answer to mimic the original code in the question, but Alan's answer is better than mine.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between ~@ and ~? I did not find any explanation. I see also that I need a quote, thanks.

Comment: Try playing in the REPL with both forms to get the difference, but in your case think about what you would have passed as `seq-exprs`. It would be a list of things. You don't want this: `[(x 1 y 2)]`, but rather this: `[x 1 y 2]`.